Historiography of the Holocaust and its ethical dimension
I am interested in understanding the development of Holocaust historiography and how the process of documenting and accounting for World War II, especially the Holocaust, unfolded during the 20th century. Specifically, I am looking for some insights however humble about the following:

Initial works that emerged as part of the early efforts to
document and write about Holocaust.
Whether historians and philosophers in the process of documenting and writing about the Holocaust and WWII explicitly took ethical positions

My curiosity in asking about ethical principles and referring to Holocaust as case study stems from the rational that understanding the ethical stances taken by historians and philosophers in their work can shed light on the moral dimensions of Holocaust historiography and how scholars grappled with the ethical implications of documenting and interpreting a dark chapter of our human history.

Why in the world would you ask this on a philosophy site?

The exploration of Holocaust historiography and the documentation of World War II, particularly the Holocaust, is a multifaceted and complex journey through scholarship:
Early Efforts in Documentation: The aftermath of World War II saw a surge in testimonies and memoirs from survivors eager to bear witness to the horrors they endured. These firsthand accounts provided invaluable insights into the human experience of the Holocaust, detailing the systematic persecution, deportation, and extermination of millions of Jews and other targeted groups. Raul Hilberg's "The Destruction of the European Jews" stands as a monumental achievement in Holocaust historiography. Hilberg meticulously traced the bureaucratic machinery behind the Final Solution, revealing the intricate networks of state institutions, Nazi officials, and collaborators that facilitated the genocide. His work set a new standard for scholarly inquiry into the Holocaust, emphasizing the importance of archival research and historical accuracy.
Evolution of Accountability: Over the decades, Holocaust scholarship expanded beyond individual narratives to encompass broader themes of collaboration, resistance, and complicity. Historians like Christopher Browning, in his seminal work "Ordinary Men," examined the actions of ordinary German soldiers who participated in mass shootings on the Eastern Front. Browning's research challenged prevailing notions of collective guilt, highlighting the complex interplay of obedience, peer pressure, and ideological indoctrination. Similarly, Daniel Goldhagen's controversial book "Hitler's Willing Executioners" sparked intense debate by arguing that ordinary Germans possessed a deep-seated "eliminationist" anti-Semitism that predisposed them to commit genocide. While Goldhagen's thesis drew criticism for its simplistic portrayal of German society, it underscored the need to confront uncomfortable truths about the perpetrators' motivations and agency.
Ethical Positions of Historians and Philosophers: Historians and philosophers engaged in Holocaust historiography often grappled with profound ethical questions about the nature of evil, moral responsibility, and historical truth. Hannah Arendt's coverage of the Adolf Eichmann trial in Jerusalem raised thorny issues about bureaucratic complicity and the banality of evil. Arendt's critique of Jewish leadership and her portrayal of Eichmann as an unremarkable bureaucrat ignited fierce controversy but forced readers to confront uncomfortable truths about the nature of genocide. Meanwhile, survivors-turned-writers like Primo Levi and Elie Wiesel infused their works with existential reflections on suffering, resilience, and the search for meaning in the midst of unfathomable darkness. Levi's "Survival in Auschwitz" and Wiesel's "Night" offered searing firsthand accounts of life in the concentration camps, challenging readers to confront the moral complexities of survival and bearing witness.
Moral Judgments and Ethical Implications: The moral judgments made by historians and philosophers in their work on the Holocaust reflected a wide spectrum of perspectives and approaches. Some scholars focused on condemning the perpetrators and affirming the dignity of the victims, emphasizing the imperative of remembrance and historical justice. Others adopted a more nuanced approach, exploring the ambiguities of human behavior and the ethical dilemmas faced by individuals living under totalitarian regimes. The ethical implications of Holocaust historiography extended beyond scholarly debates to encompass broader questions about memory, representation, and the responsibilities of future generations. Historians grappled with the challenge of preserving the integrity of survivor testimonies while acknowledging the limitations of memory and interpretation. Moreover, the proliferation of Holocaust denial and revisionism underscored the ongoing importance of rigorous scholarship and ethical engagement in confronting historical distortions and safeguarding the truth.

Well, I guess we can divide all of it into 4 parts. At least roughly.
Initial Documentation Phase (1945-1960s)
The immediate postwar years - gathering firsthand testimonies from survivors and collecting evidence of the atrocities. Elie Wiesel's "Night" (1958) and Primo Levi's "If This Is a Man" (1947) providing personal accounts from the camps. Organizations like the Wiener Library and Yad Vashem began archiving a collection of Holocaust-related materials
Early Historical Accounts (1950s-1960s)
The next phase - the publication of some of the earliest comprehensive scholarly works such as Raul Hilberg's seminal "The Destruction of the European Jews" (1961) and Gerald Reitlinger's "The Final Solution" (1953). Narrative of the Nazi genocide based on the accumullated documentation.
Broadening Perspectives and Debates (1960s onwards)
Debates and controversies such as the intentionalist vs. functionalist interpretations of the Holocaust's origins. The Goldhagen controversy, in his book "Hitler's Willing Executioners" (1996), debates over the complicity of ordinary Germans in the atrocities.
Ethical and Moral Dimensions (1960s onwards)
While the primary goal was documentation and analysis based on evidence, many folks grappled with the profound ethical and moral questions raised by the Holocaust. Hannah Arendt's "Eichmann in Jerusalem" (1963) - concept of the "banality of evil" and moral responsibilities of individuals. Hilberg and Christopher Browning - culpability of various actors, from high-ranking Nazi officials to ordinary citizens.
